# What is the YUV format of the decoded hevc file with using libde265

Tags: c++, yuv, hevc

i'm using libde265([www.libde265.org](http://www.libde265.org)) to decode my hevc file in c++ project and try to save the decoded YUV as pictures. But i hava a problem to find the address of the Y,U,V values in c++ project.
Does anybody know, which format of YUV we get, when we use libde265 decode a hevc file? YUV420, YUV420P, YUV420SP, etc.?

Thanks a lot!
Ivan

Comment: I have worked on video projects where I had to find the specification of the codec which does tell all ... onerous yet laden with treasures ... essential when zero help found elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many things :-) And i think that is YUV420P and has 3 planes.
Using the method

```
const uint8_t* de265_get_image_plane(const struct de265_image*, int channel, int* out_stride);
```

we can get the Y from channel 1 and u,v from channel 2 and 3.